# Create a matrix with a column of 1s and a column of the data

Tags: python, matrix

I have 100 data points for my x variable and I want to put them into a matrix but with a column on 1s before it in the matrix as well. So it would look like [1 1 1 ....
[x1 x2 .....]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you make the example better please so I can give a correct answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

##### Assuming the array is a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.random.random(size=100)
ones = np.ones(shape=len(array))
```

output:

```
# xs (100 values)
array([3.50037538e-01, 1.08917935e-01, 7.91498597e-01, 3.60795423e-01,
       ...
       5.72706863e-01, 4.58894874e-01, 2.42843260e-01, 6.09427238e-01])

# ones (100 values)
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       ...
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

###### merging both in the same dimension

```
>>> np.r_[ones, xs]
np.array([1., 1., ... 1., 3.50037538e-01, 1.08917935e-01, ...])
```

###### merging as columns

```
>>> np.c_[ones, xs]
array([[1.00000000e+00, 3.50037538e-01],
       [1.00000000e+00, 1.08917935e-01],
       [1.00000000e+00, 7.91498597e-01],
       ...
       [1.00000000e+00, 6.09427238e-01]])
```

##### Assuming a list

```
x_list = xs.tolist()
ones_list = [1]*len(x_list)
```

output:

```
# x_list (100 values)
[3.50037538e-01, 1.08917935e-01, 7.91498597e-01, 3.60795423e-01,
 ...
 5.72706863e-01, 4.58894874e-01, 2.42843260e-01, 6.09427238e-01]

# ones_list (100 values)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 ...
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

###### merging both in the same dimension

```
>>> x_list+ones_list
[1, 1,..., 1, 3.50037538e-01, 1.08917935e-01, ...]
```

###### merging both in a second dimension

```
>>>> list(zip(ones_list, x_list))
[(1, 0.3500375382514712),
 (1, 0.10891793499403313),
 ...
 (1, 0.6094272384712242)]
```